# Django bulk_create with ignore_conflicts=True giving ProgrammingError

Tags: python, django, postgresql, cpanel, web-hosting

I am getting this strange error

```
ProgrammingError at /save_hsn/
syntax error at or near "ON"
LINE 1: ...021-01-28T06:17:43.784614+00:00'::timestamptz, 1) ON CONFLIC...
```

this is my views.py part where I am getting the error

```
user_gst_codes.objects.bulk_create(hsn_list, ignore_conflicts=True)
```

If I remove `ignore_conflicts=True`, everything works.

Moreover, I start getting this error after deploying my Django app on cPanel, on localhost this doesn't give any error.

On localhost-

Python 3.6.6, Django 3.1

On cPanel-

Python 3.6.11, Django 3.1

Is this an issue with the Python version?

I am inserting data in bulk and also need to keep the unique check.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you using postgresql? which db?

Comment: yes, I am using PostgreSQL on both localhost and on cPanel

Comment: I have problem in this issue!(Error While Importing Data:  ignore_conflicts and update_conflicts are mutually exclusive.)

could you solve your problem?

Comment: @arezoo, yes, The isssue was the PostgreSQL version was 8.4.20 which was giving the error, I upgraded the PostgreSQL version to the latest and everything worked fine. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the ON CONFLICT clause is only available from PostgreSQL 9.5. If you are using an earlier version, you will need a workaround to have the upsert feature. Please check local postgresql version and server postgresql version.

Comment: On local, I'm using PostgreSQL 12.3, and on cPanel,  I am unsure which version I've got installed from the hosting company.

Comment: https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/sql/install-or-update-postgresql-on-your-cpanel-server/ this would help

Comment: I contacted my hosting support and got to know that the PostgreSQL version on the server is 8.4.20.

Comment: ok. good, let them know you want to upgrade above 9.5, or have to modify the django code everywhere according to the old postgresql version